# How do i assert in groovy with multple scenarios?

Tags: function, methods, groovy, ready-api

I am testing an API using ReadyAPI and currently I am trying to figure some solution for the following situation:

I run 3 request in parallel that can affect the way they respond. The test is to add an object to a list and get errors on the other two lists and the item should be added to only one of them.

So far so good. but when running in parallel, the status codes modifi:
Ex:
First run:
Test 1 - 200
Test 2 - 400
Test 3 - 400
Cleanup

Second run:
Test 1 -400
Test 2 -200
Test 3 -400
Cleanup

Possibly 3rd run: (it isn't a predictable situation)
Test 1 - 200
Test 2 - 200
Test 3 - 400

The only way i thought of so far is to create a groovy assertion function so that it can assert and return the current statuses and to asset that 3rd run is exposed. Bear in mind that it is not always the third run that can generate this result. Any ideeas on how that function should work?

```
def A = 200
def B = 400
def C = 400

def assesmentFunct(a, b,c){
assert a = a
assert b = b
assert c = c
}

assesmentFunct(A,B,C)
```

The thig is that i can have 3 scenarios where 200 is possible so i am thinking of some kind of matrix of assetions
Please help

Tried *if else* nessted, switch-case

Comment: are you trying to just create a 2D array and loop through it?

Comment: collect results into an array and it's easy to assert whole array. `assert results.count{it==200} == 1` - that's just an example - I can't understand the expected result from your question...

Comment: @daggett this is what I did as a last resort. The expected result is actually to prove the presence of a race condition. when sending 3 requests  at the same time to the service it should return only one 200 and the other two 400. So the expected result would be a=200, b=400, c =400 or a = 400, b=200, c=400 and so on. there are 8 possible responses from which only 3 are  valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

collect results into an array and assert the array

```
def results = [200,400,400]

assert results in [
    [400,400,200],
    [400,200,400],
    [200,400,400]
]
```